# Vaadin : How to change favicon?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

How can I change favicon of my pages in Vaadin ? I would like to change favicon of my pages but I have no idea where is the place to change it ? Has somebody experience on it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, create a theme directory: /WebContent/VAADIN/themes/mynewtheme

Then, put your custom favicon.ico in this directory. You also need to set theme property in your application :

```
public class MyNewApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        ...
        ...
        setTheme("mynewtheme");
    }
}
```

Comment: If my icon name is **custom.ico** instead of **favicon.ico** , will it be work ?

Comment: Very strange... I have the @Theme("mytheme") annotation over my UI class but I have to call setTheme("mytheme") ONCE to change favicon...

Answer (score 7):

Here is a more detailed version of the [similar Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25660853/642706) posted by Greg Ballot. My Answer here relates to Vaadin 7, current as of 7.5.3.

## Custom Theme

In [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) 7.5, you can drop your favicon graphics image file into [your own custom theme](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.creating.html). If using the Vaadin plugin for various [IDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) ([NetBeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50531/vaadin-plug-in-for-netbeans), [Eclipse](http://vaadin.com/eclipse)) or the [Maven archetypes](https://vaadin.com/maven), a custom theme named `mytheme` should have already been created for you. Drop your image file into that `mytheme` folder.

The main part of your Vaadin 7 app, your subclass of `UI`, must specify that it uses your custom theme. Again, if using the IDE plugins and/or Maven archetype, this should have already been configured for you. The easiest way is an Java Annotation on the UI subclass.

```
@Theme ( "mytheme" )  // Tell Vaadin to apply your custom theme, usually a subclass of the Valo or Reindeer theme.
@Title ( "PowerWrangler" )  // Statically specify the title to appear in web browser window/tab.
@SuppressWarnings ( "serial" )  // If not serializing such as "sticky sessions" and such, disable compiler warnings about serialization.
@Push ( PushMode.AUTOMATIC )  // If using Push technology.
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI
{
…
```

## Favicon Usage/Behavior Not Standard

Remember that favicon behavior is not standardized. Favicons developed haphazardly, mostly out of a sense of fun. The exact behavior depends on the particular browser and particular server. Other than the particular folder location, none of this is special to Vaadin.

## Image File Formats

Originally the [ICO file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)) was used exclusively. Since then most browsers have evolved to accept any of several formats including [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), [TIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format), and [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG).

## Image Size/Resolution

Originally favicons were intended to be very small bitmap icons. Some browsers have made various uses of the favicon in situations where you may want to provide a higher-resolution image. But remember that smaller files load faster without keeping your users waiting.

## Favicon File Name

Some browsers or servers may handle other file names or name extensions, but I've found it easiest to name my file exactly `favicon.ico` -- even if using a different format! I usually use a PNG file but name it with the .ico extension. While I cannot guarantee this practice works one every server and browser, I’ve not encountered any problem.

## Existing Favicon File

Recent versions of Vaadin have included a Vaadin-related icon in a favicon.ico file in a configured project. So you must replace that file with your own. In Vaadin 7.5.3 the file contains four sizes, the largest looking like this:

[image: Vaadin logo favicon provided by default in a configured project]

Older versions did not add a file, so you drop in your own.

## IDE Screen Shots

Here are a pair of screen shots. One is the project (logical) view in NetBeans 8, while the other is a files (physical) view.

[image: Project view of a favicon’s location, using NetBeans 8]

[image: File system view of a favicon’s location, using NetBeans 8]

Answer (score 4):

In case of custom icon name (Vaadin 7):

```
public class MyServlet extends VaadinServlet implements SessionInitListener {

    @Override
    protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized();
        getService().addSessionInitListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionInit(SessionInitEvent event) throws ServiceException {
        event.getSession().addBootstrapListener(new BootstrapListener() {

            @Override
            public void modifyBootstrapPage(BootstrapPageResponse response) {
                response.getDocument().head()
                  .getElementsByAttributeValue("rel", "shortcut icon")
                    .attr("href", "./VAADIN/themes/mynewtheme/custom.ico");
                response.getDocument().head()
                  .getElementsByAttributeValue("rel", "icon")
                    .attr("href", "./VAADIN/themes/mynewtheme/custom.ico");
            }

            @Override
            public void modifyBootstrapFragment(BootstrapFragmentResponse response) {
            }

        });
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

It is better to use the `BootstrapListener` as a static nested class: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161930/java-io-notserializableexception-is-thrown-while-restarting-vaadin-application)

Comment: I appreciate this answer, BUT: I applied this to my project with `.../favicon.png").attr("type", "image/png");` and nothing is displayed as favicon in my browser's tab. If I disable/comment the newly applied not even Vaadin's default favicon is displayed any longer. (v7.5.0.rc1)

Comment: Well, that's funny. I just discovered that the correct favicon is displayed in FF's History. It's just/still not displayed in the page's tab.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Recent versions of web browsers have been changing their usage of favicons. Some browsers display the favicon in a tab, some do not. Some display in the URL address bar, some do not. Some display in a bookmarks menu, some do not.

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin 23.x (plain spring/war application, no springboot!):

Derive an implementation of com.vaadin.flow.component.page.AppShellConfigurator:

```
@Theme(value = "mytheme")
@PWA(name = "My application", shortName = "MyApp", iconPath = "icons/favicon.ico" )
public class AppShellConfiguratiorImpl implements AppShellConfigurator {
    @Override
    public void configurePage(AppShellSettings settings) {
        settings.addFavIcon("icon", "icons/favicon.ico", "16x16");
    }
}
```

And put your favicon.ico into src\main\webapp\icons (in order that it is encluded in `<war-root>/icons/favicon.ico`)

A servlet container (3.0 plus, e.g. Tomcat 8.5) will pick up this class automagically and load it.