# How to add image logo with URL in vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I use vaadin 7.5.3 
I want to add logo my web site page top with
logo Url : http://...../example.png

But I want to read image on internet URL

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vaadin : How to change favicon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660659/vaadin-how-to-change-favicon)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ExternalResource` with the `Image` component to display an image from an external URL:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.setSource(new ExternalResource("http://www.maski.gov.tr/Maski.PNG"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Image image = new Image();
image.setSource(new ExternalResource("http://www.maski.gov.tr/Maski.PNG")); 
image.setWidth("207px");
image.setHeight("80px");
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd do something more simple. I'd add a label with some HTML like this.

```
Label logo = new Label("<a href=\"http://www.maski.gov.tr\"><img src=\"http://www.maski.gov.tr/Maski.PNG\"></a>", ContentMode.HTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who finds this answer while searching for a more recent version of Vaadin, this worked for me in Vaadin v24:

```
private Image iconImage = new Image();
String iconURL = "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/few?size=medium";
iconImage.setSrc(iconURL);
```