# favicon.ico disappearing adding server.context-path in vaadin 8 spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin8

I updated context-path to my application.properties and favicon.ico is not being shown aafter that.

If I am removing server.context-path=/myApp from application.properties it is working. I wonder if there is a way to define favicon.icon for application with contextpath.

I had favicon.ico in this path:
src/main/resources/VAADIN/themes/myApp/

Comment: Please share html code for favicon.ico.

Comment: I have never used Vaadin so perhaps this answer is a bit far-fetched as you use the default `favicon.ico` filename, but you can perhaps consider this as a possible workaround. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660659/vaadin-how-to-change-favicon/25667111#25667111

Comment: @IssamEL-ATIF this is the code for favico: <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="./VAADIN/themes/myApp/favicon.ico">

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not adding server.context-path attribute. I changed the pom file adding this code

```
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

The filtering changed the shape of favicon so it was not recognizable.